# How to write a test case for Sequelize.js raw query in Sequelize Mock in Node.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sequelize.js

I am unable to understand to write a test case for a raw query in sequelizejs using  Sequelize Mock.

**My function which is returning coupons object on success with 200 status**

```
try {
    const domain = req.params.domain;
    const domainFilter = { domain: { [Op.eq]: req.params.domain } };
    const merchant = await models.merchants.findOne({ where: domainFilter });
    if (merchant) {
        const coupons = await models.sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM coupons LEFT JOIN coupon_activities ON coupons.coupon=coupon_activities.coupon WHERE coupons.domain='${domain}' ORDER BY coupon_activities.best_discount DESC, coupon_activities.worked DESC, coupons.expire_date DESC LIMIT 50`, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
        if (coupons && coupons.length > 0) {
            const keys = [...new Set(coupons[0].map(el => el.coupon))]
            const filteredCoupons = coupons[0].filter(el => {
                if (keys.indexOf(el.coupon) !== -1) {
                    keys.splice(keys.indexOf(el.coupon), 1)
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            res.status(200).send({ coupons: filteredCoupons });
        } else {
            res.status(204).send({ response: "No Coupons" });
        }
    } else {
        res.status(204).send({ response: "No Content" });
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send({ response: "Error in server" });
}
```

**Test case for function**

```
describe('Get Coupons By Merchand Id', () => {
    it('It got all coupons of a merchant', (done) => {
        const merchant_id = 1;
        chai.request(server)
        .get('/api/coupons/' + merchant_id)
        .end((err, res) => {
            res.should.have.status(200);
            res.body.should.be.a('object');
            res.body.should.not.have.property('errors');
            res.body.coupons.length.should.not.equal(0);
            res.body.coupons[0].merchant_id.should.be.equal(merchant_id);
        done();
        });
    });
});
```

**Mock i have setup**

```
'use strict';
const dbMock = require('./sequelize_mock');
const Op = dbMock.Op;

let SequelizeMock = dbMock.define("sequelize", {
  merchant_id: 1,
  domain: 'amazon.com',
  coupon: 'TESTCOUPON',
  description: 'This is a test',
  expiry_date: '12-12-9999', 
}, {
  indexes: [{ fields: ['merchant_id'] }],
  createdAt: false,
  updatedAt: false,
  id: false,
  tableName: 'coupons',
});

SequelizeMock.$queryInterface.$useHandler(function(query, queryOptions, done) {
  console.log('TCL: query', query)
    console.log('TCL: queryOptions', queryOptions)
});

module.exports = SequelizeMock;
```

But it is not working giving me error can someone help me setup this mock correctly so i can send back data based on query or something which works.

**Currently getting error sequelize is not defined**

Answer (score 0):

Same here, i search the sequelize-mock documentation and there is nothing about this. But i found this example on github:

> If you're using the sequelize.query() function, you can queue up
>   results on the mock sequelize object to be returned from that function
>   as well. Like with models, you simply need to use the .$queueResult()
>   method.

https://github.com/BlinkUX/sequelize-mock/issues/53

Answer (score 0):

I use Jest for testing. and facing the same problem for mocking the raw query. after spending lots of time I found one solution.

```
describe('your test case', () => {

test('test function ', async () => {
    let sequelizeMock = {
        query: (function(){
            return [{
                 merchant_id: 1,
                 domain: 'amazon.com',
                 coupon: 'TESTCOUPON',
                 description: 'This is a test',
                 expiry_date: '12-12-9999',
            }]
        }),
        QueryTypes: {
            SELECT: ''
        }
    }
    const mockFn = jest.mock();
    sequelizeConnectionMock.sequelize = sequelizeMock
    mockFn.spyOn(db, 'connection').mockReturnValue(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { return resolve(sequelizeConnectionMock) }))
})
```